# Does a Tello Drone require the Tello App to run?

Tags: dji-sdk, tello-drone

Basically, is the Tello App (running on a mobile device) an optional piece of equipment or is it required for the drone to operate?

Comment: The Tello doesn't come with a remote control. Another device is required, and Ryze doesn't offer one as an accessory. Ryze publishes an SDK that allows developers to develop alternative applications to control the Tello drone, and receive video and other telemetry. There are some software repositories with examples of the code to do this in github, and there are probably alternative apps in apps stores for various mobile operating systems.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. You can find the documentation on the API here: https://www.ryzerobotics.com/tello/downloads I highly recommend the drone. It is fun and easy to fly with the app, and fun to hack with code. The official app may use an unpublished protocol rather than the one described in the SDK document. If you look around you might find people who have worked to reverse engineer it.

Comment: How can i connect to the Tello?

Comment: The SDK documentation I linked to describes how to do it. It's oriented toward developers; given your reputation and profile, I'm guessing that would be enough to get you started. But, basically, the Tello acts as a WiFi access point. When you connect to that, you can send UDP datagrams with supported commands to a hard-coded IP address and port.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It need's a phone (or tablet), and to download the app, you can go to *[here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryzerobotics.tello)*. The drone is connected via wifi, and the wifi name should be fairly to recognize: 'TELLO - *xxxxxx*'. The app is easy to use, the left one controls the height and rotation, and the right one controls the position. There are also some warnings, including: Can't use video positioning and others.

Hope you like my answer! (Maybe I'm wrong?)

Comment: This does not answer OP's question: is the App mandatory or not?

Comment: @MatteoV I explained that it needs a phone or tablet to run

Comment: For future reference: The Tello does NOT require a phone or tablet to be controlled. see @Keshav.h answer.

Answer (score 1):

a tello doesnt require an app. the app just sends commands to the drone. you can control the drone from python, javascript .. whatever you want (except for some). you can basically connect to the drone from your computer and send messages to it. an example is "takeoff" and "land", i dont know how you wanna do that but some ways are, as i already said, python or javascript. check this video for python, the easiest method:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LmEcyQnfpDA

Comment: edit: if you wanna do it with javascript and nodejs then here: (an npm nodejs library for controlling a tello from javascript ):: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tello-drone